k8s ingress issue: no value in address field
This is the ingress configuration of a service (my-service), ingress.yml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-service-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  labels:
    app: my-service
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - my-service.my-domain.com
  rules:
  - host: my-service.my-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              number: 3000

When I deploy the service everything is ok but when I run kubectl get ingress I see that my-service has no value in ADDRESS column and the endpoint is not available (default backend - 404).
NAME                CLASS  HOSTS                             ADDRESS      PORTS     AGE
my-service-ingress  <none> my-service-ingress.my-domain.com               80, 443   14h
2nd-service-ingress <none> 2nd-service-ingress.my-domain.com 10.100.83.4  80, 443   2y302d

I'm not expert in k8s and I apoligise if I'm not precise in the terms or I'm missing something, but I would like to understand where should I look at in order to figure out what to do.
One more thing,

I just changed the apiVersion from extensions/v1beta1 to networking.k8s.io/v1, of course changing ingress.yml as well.
my-service was just created in the cluster, I mean I created it with new apiVersion
Existing ones created with older apiVersion had no impact when I deployed them with the new apiVersion in their ingress.yml file.

This is the output of kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17+", GitVersion:"v1.17.7-eks-bffbac", GitCommit:"bffbacfd13a805a12d10ccc0ca26205ae1ca76e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-07-08T18:30:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22+", GitVersion:"v1.22.17-eks-db838b0", GitCommit:"c7efe93233465b95c6ca98462098e5320a997684", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2024-06-27T19:10:34Z", GoVersion:"go1.21.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

I also changed the deprecated annotation kubernetes.io/ingress.class with ingressClassName but same behaviour.
